# View SQL entries that were entered within past 24 hours

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am trying to view the entries into my sql database that were entered within the last 24 hours. My database has a Date and Time field that are set when the record is entered. I am currently using the following code but it is not working. The is code executed correctly so I suspect that my SQL query is incorrect.

```
DateTime Time = DateTime.Now;
Time = Time.Subtract(new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0)); //Get DateTime of 24 Hours Ago
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM DataTable WHERE Date>'" + Time.ToShortDateString() + "' AND Time>'" + Time.ToShortTimeString() + "'";
```

My Table name is correct and the field names are correct.

Thanks

Comment: Do you receive some specific error while you execute the query? Try to print the sql statement you are sending to the database and try to exceute it through a database specific client. It can be easier to find any SQL syntax error

Comment: You could always do it all on the db (assuming mssql) `SELECT * FROM DataTable WHERE Date>=dateadd(day, -1, getdate())`

Comment: @ab_dev86 Code is executed without errors he says. However he seems to have a separate date and time column.

Comment: @keni I know using seperate date and time fields are bad practice but I I'm writing a web page to do some queries only (extending functionality of site), I'm not allowed to modify the table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delimit your field names since they are reserved keywords:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = 
"SELECT * FROM DataTable WHERE [Date]>'" + Time.ToShortDateString() + "' AND [Time]>'" + Time.ToShortTimeString() + "'"
```

This is a very good reason to choose field names that are not reserved words in SQL.

If these are both one field, then you can just do a single evaluation of Date and Time:

`WHERE <datetime field name> > GetDate() - 1`

Comment: thank you very much. Forgot about reserved words. Time to hit the SQL textbook again.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM DataTable WHERE [DATE] > getdate() - 1
```